# How to iterate through a set to get field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, facet

Can somebody tell me please if is possible to iterate through a set to create a field value for key in mongodb result. If I have $facet state in pipeline like:

```
'missing': [{'$group': {'_id': '$foo', 'woo': {'$addToSet': '$wwo'}}},
           {'$project': {'missing_woo': {'$setDifference': [woo_set, '$woo']}}
```

I would like to get result where code value will be the key like

```
{'missing_woo': 'missing_woo1'}, {'missing_woo': 'missing_woo2'},... {'missing_woo': 'missing_wooN'}
```

so that I can iterate through the set generated at $project and to create field values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `$unwind`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      missing: [
        {$group: {_id: "$foo", woo: {$addToSet: "$wwo"}}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, missing_woo: 
          {$setDifference: [
                [
                  "woo1",
                  "woo2",
                  "wooN",
                  "missing_woo1",
                  "missing_woo2",
                  "missing_wooN"
                ],
                "$woo"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {$unwind: "$missing_woo"}
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/klfHC_dJIzy)

Comment: nimrod's answer is correct. thank you

Comment: nimrod - would you be willing to look at a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72918612/17563642