# How to pick a string from set if string is in field value of collection - MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Can somebody tell me please if is possible to iterate through a set, check whether a field value contains the set string and return the set string in MongoDB aggregation?

If I have a collection like:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "a",
    "name": "tomas",
    
  },
  {
    "foo": "a",
    "name": "herbas",
    
  },

]
```

a set like this:

```
(TOM, Herb)
```

I would like to get result where:

```
{'name_abbr': 'TOM'}, {'name_abbr': 'HERB'}
```

I've played with $setDifference and $regexMatch but can't figure out how to return the set substring that is contained the collection's given field value.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your expected results exactly, but if I understand correctly and you want to check which strings in your set can be matched as a regex to one of your documents `name`, you can do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      results: {
        $reduce: {
          input: inputSet,
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$regexMatch: {input: "$name", regex: "$$this", options: "i"}},
                  [{name_abbr: "$$this"}],
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id: 0, res: {$push: "$results"}}},
  {$set: {
    _id: "$$REMOVE", 
    res: {$reduce: {
          input: "$res",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fM4Eg9tBNu8)

Is this answering your question?

Comment: Yes. You are a true friend. Thank you.